# Where are the window manager config files?

Tags: compiz, kubuntu, kde

Where are the window manager config files? 
in Kubuntu-11.04

Comment: They are "hidden" in your home directory. Hidden files have a "." in the front. For kde they are in `~/.kde`. what are you looking for exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

They are "hidden" in your home directory. Hidden files have a "." in the front. For kde they are in ~/.kde. what are you looking for exactly ? – bodhi.zazen Dec 11 '11 at 23:30